# DELETE with two joined table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-delete, join

I got two tables NOTIF and PJ_GEN defined like this :

```
TABLE NOTIF
==========
ID_NOTIF
COD_ONE
LIB
DATE

TABLE PJ_GEN
==========
ID_PJ
COD_TWO
LIB_TWO
```

There's a many to many association, defined by this table :

```
PJ_BY_NOTIF
==========
ID_NOTIF
ID_PJ
```

I want to write a request to delete all tables, starting by NOTIF table. My basis request is :

```
DELETE * FROM NOTIF WHERE DATE < ? AND COD_ONE = 3;
```

How can I update this request two delete both of joined tables PJ_GEN and PJ_BY_NOTIF ?

PJ_BY_NOTF has two foreign key : `ID_NOTIF` and `ID_PJ`

**SOLUTION :**

I find a way by adding `on delete cascade` on he `ID_PJ` foreign key in `PJ_BY_NOTIF`

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @User3469203 you have one loop in your solution proposed in question .. how you will be deleting from PJ_GEN table with this approach?

Comment: I made two statements : first I delete from PJ_GEN, and this delete from PJ_BY_NOTIF too (thanks to the ON DELETE CASCADE). And then I delete from NOTIF.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can first delete from `PJ_GEN` table using condition from `NOTIF` joining `PJ_BY-NOTIF` 
Like

```
Delete from PJ_GEN where ID_PJ in 
          (select ID_PJ from PJ_BY_NOTIF ,NOTIF 
                       where NOTIF.ID_NOTIF = PJ_BY_NOTIF.ID_NOTIF
                       and NOTIF.DATE < ? AND COD_ONE = 3);
```

and then you can issue one delete statement to delete from `PJ_BY_NOTIF` table to remove Many to many association relation

```
DELETE from PJ_BY_NOTIF WHERE ID_PJ IN 
                     ( SELECT ID_PJ 
                        FROM NOTIF 
                         WHERE NOTIF.DATE < ? AND COD_ONE = 3);
```

:**Edit**: If foreign key is present in intermediate table `PJ_BY_NOTIF` then you need to make sure that foreign key had been defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint, if not then do this change. If `ON DELETE CASCADE` is defined then this will automatically delete corresponding child records from child table and you will not be require to use this second delete statement.

**Edit 2** - But as this is many to many relation maintained in this scenario, this would interfere the relation with other value.
It means that if you have one `ID_PJ` having two `ID_NOTIF` defined out of which one NOTIF you are going to delete from master table and so you are trying to delete from PJ_GEN based on your condition. But as one other ID_NOTIF is also associated with this ID_PJ, you should skip this particular ID_PJ to delete from PJ_GEN table.

and then delete finally from `NOTIF` table.

```
DELETE FROM NOTIF 
WHERE NOTIF.DATE < ? AND COD_ONE = 3
```

Comment: The first statement doesn't work, because there's a foreign key in PJ_GEN which reference NOTIF primary key : 'java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint <PJ_BY_NOTIF_00_FK> violated - child record found

Comment: Please check whether you have any other table referring PJ_GEN table .. because as you are telling you have foreign key in PJ_GEN then it should be okay deleting rows from this table first .. as this will be considered as child table in this case ..

Comment: one more thing .. please check again .. as you are mentioning that it is having many to many relation, it should not be having any relation with PJ_GEN and NOTIF.. this relation should only be accomplish by one intermediate table which you are already using `PJ_BY_NOTIF`

Comment: There's no other table referring to PJ_GEN. I have just foreign keys in PJ_BY_NOTIF, not in PJ_GEN. You're right, the relation is only accomplished by PJ_BY_NOYIF.

Comment: I find a way by adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign key in PJ_BY_NOTIF. Tks for help

Comment: yes. if you have foreign key present then in this case you should use `ON DELETE CASCADE ` while defining foreign key to effect this requirement.